# JSON RPC 2.0: response that is part error and part result

Tags: json-rpc

What is the standard approach to returning a JSON RPC response when there is only partial failure? It appears that [both 'result' and 'error' cannot both be set](http://www.jsonrpc.org/specification).

We have a case where a server is aggregating results across several sites running the same API. The reason for the aggregation is due to the [Same-Origin Policy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy). Each site may respond with either a result or an error. If some respond with a result and others with an error, then what does the aggregation server return as the complete response to the original caller?

```
a =(method)=> b
              b =(method)=> c
              b =(method)=> d
              b <=(error)== c
              b <=(result)= d
a <=(??????)= b
```

Is it best to simply return two responses (one with any errors and no 'id' and one with the results and an 'id' suggesting this is the last response)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The server responsibility is to aggregate and return the results, which may contain errors. This is what your client is expecting.

```
--> {"jsonrpc": "2.0", "method": "getResults", "id": 1}

<-- {"jsonrpc": "2.0", "result": [ "success", "error" ], "id": 1}
```

You should return an error if the server itself could not process the request, for any unexpected reason.

Comment: This does appear to answer the original question, but I have to say that there is something left to be desired regardless. What if server "C" responds significantly quicker than server "D"? Should the client "A" really be made to wait the additional amount of time for the complete result?

Comment: @GregSmethells Yes. JSON-RPC has one response for one request. There are some discussion about [progress notification](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/json-rpc/8Ea6qu_u_tU), but is not available yet.